# Is there any way to have a name for angular 2 routes?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Is there any way to have named routes in Angular? Maybe something like this

```
{
  path: '',
  loadChildren: './components/module#Module',
  name: 'namedRoutes'
}
```

So all I need to do is call the route's name to navigate, not to call the absolute path.

Comment: You can use path for navigate as explained [here](https://angular.io/guide/router#lazy-loading-route-configuration)

Answer (score 2):

There is **NO** way to have named routes in new Angular2 router.
You can read the **[documentation](https://angular.io/guide/router)** .

If you really want to use named routes , check this **[Named Router Outlets in Angular 2](http://onehungrymind.com/named-router-outlets-in-angular-2/)**. Hope it helps.

Comment: _There is a way to have named r_ - can you point to the specific place in document ion where this is shown?

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no way in Angular router for naming the routes. You could use [UI-Router](https://ui-router.github.io/ng2/) for facilitating what you ask for and handle routes even more conveniently.